# Can't manage to export multiple rows from database to XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table with 3 rows, 1 is being used as row identifier, 2nd is used to make a relation with other table, and 3rd holds content. I'm doing a query where the the given result is kind of what I need but has a little mistake.

Table:[image: print]

Here's the query that I'm using:

```
SELECT Plate, tbl_veiculos.ID, Section, Category, Brand, Model, Version, Fuel, Price, B2BPrice, Year, Month, TollClass, Origin, Color, SeatColour, Seats, Kms, Doors, HP, Owners, CC, Obs, TaxDeductible, WarrantyMonth,
(SELECT Name, Street, Locality, Email from tbl_AdStand where tbl_AdStand.ID = tbl_veiculos.ID AND tbl_veiculos.ID = 1 FOR XML PATH('AdStand'), type ), 
(SELECT DISTINCT Site from tbl_ExportSites where tbl_ExportSites.ID = tbl_veiculos.ID AND tbl_veiculos.ID = 1 FOR XML PATH('ExportSites'), type )
FROM tbl_veiculos, tbl_veiculo_spec, tbl_AdStand
WHERE tbl_veiculos.ID = tbl_veiculo_spec.ID AND tbl_AdStand.ID = tbl_veiculos.ID AND tbl_veiculos.ID = 1
FOR XML PATH ('Vehicle'), TYPE, ROOT('VehicleList')
```

Here's the output that I get:

```
<VehicleList>
  <Vehicle>
    <Plate>34-23-nd</Plate>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Section>carros</Section>
    <Category>cabrio</Category>
    <Brand>Mercedes-Benz</Brand>
    <Model>A140</Model>
    <Version>1.4 twin-turbo</Version>
    <Fuel>Gasolina</Fuel>
    <Price>18.000</Price>
    <B2BPrice>0</B2BPrice>
    <Year>2015</Year>
    <Month>03</Month>
    <TollClass>2</TollClass>
    <Origin>Alemanha</Origin>
    <Color>Vermelho</Color>
    <SeatColour>Cinza</SeatColour>
    <Seats>5</Seats>
    <Kms>13000</Kms>
    <Doors>5</Doors>
    <HP>310</HP>
    <Owners>0</Owners>
    <CC>1.389</CC>
    <Obs>Tinta raspada no para-choques dianteiro</Obs>
    <WarrantyMonth>0</WarrantyMonth>
    <AdStand>
      <Name>Stand Veloso</Name>
      <Street>Rua dos Biscainhos</Street>
      <Locality>2450-341</Locality>
      <Email>standbisca@gmail.com</Email>
    </AdStand>
    <ExportSites>
      <Site>Coisas</Site>
    </ExportSites>
    <ExportSites>
      <Site>Custojusto</Site>
    </ExportSites>
    <ExportSites>
      <Site>StandVirtual</Site>
    </ExportSites>
  </Vehicle>
</VehicleList>
```

The "mistake" is in the last lines

```
        <ExportSites>
              <Site>Coisas</Site>
            </ExportSites>
            <ExportSites>
              <Site>Custojusto</Site>
            </ExportSites>
            <ExportSites>
              <Site>StandVirtual</Site>
            </ExportSites>
```

The output apears "separated" while I need absolutelly opposite, I need it to appear like this [hardcoded]:

```
            <ExportSites>
              <Site>Coisas</Site>
              <Site>Custojusto</Site>
              <Site>StandVirtual</Site>
            </ExportSites>
```

What do I need to change in my query so that I get this. Also, can I later export this query with PHP to an XML file?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Next time, when you place a question, please reduce it to the needed minimum. All columns which are not needed to point to the issue, should be taken away. Just let one or two of them in place to show the structure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE([Site] VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES ('Site 1'),('Site 2');

SELECT [Site] FROM @mockup FOR XML PATH('ExportSites'),TYPE;
SELECT [Site] FROM @mockup FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('ExportSites'),TYPE;
```

The results

```
<ExportSites>
  <Site>Site 1</Site>
</ExportSites>
<ExportSites>
  <Site>Site 2</Site>
</ExportSites>
```

and

```
<ExportSites>
  <Site>Site 1</Site>
  <Site>Site 2</Site>
</ExportSites>
```

You see the difference?

`PATH()` will specify the row's name, while `ROOT` will define an additional enclosing element. Since your row's name is empty, the columns name is *alone*...

Just for curiosity: You might try to add one more column to the *mockup*-table above and compare the difference...

So change your sub-query to:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT Site 
 from tbl_ExportSites 
 where tbl_ExportSites.ID = tbl_veiculos.ID AND tbl_veiculos.ID = 1 
 FOR XML PATH(''),ROOT('ExportSites'), type )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide the root as below:

```
SELECT Plate, tbl_veiculos.ID, Section, Category, Brand, Model, Version, Fuel, Price, B2BPrice, Year, Month, TollClass, Origin, Color, SeatColour, Seats, Kms, Doors, HP, Owners, CC, Obs, TaxDeductible, WarrantyMonth,
(SELECT Name, Street, Locality, Email from tbl_AdStand where tbl_AdStand.ID = tbl_veiculos.ID AND tbl_veiculos.ID = 1 FOR XML PATH('AdStand'), type ), 
(SELECT DISTINCT Site from tbl_ExportSites where tbl_ExportSites.ID = tbl_veiculos.ID AND tbl_veiculos.ID = 1 FOR XML PATH('Site'), type, root('ExportSites') )
FROM tbl_veiculos, tbl_veiculo_spec, tbl_AdStand
WHERE tbl_veiculos.ID = tbl_veiculo_spec.ID AND tbl_AdStand.ID = tbl_veiculos.ID AND tbl_veiculos.ID = 1
FOR XML PATH ('Vehicle'), TYPE, ROOT('VehicleList')
```

Comment: It is not advisable to do cartesian product instead of explicit joins. Use explicit joins

Comment: I tried but haven't had success, it's outputs this                 
 `<ExportSites>
      <Site>
        <Site>Coisas</Site>
      </Site>
      <Site>
        <Site>Custojusto</Site>
      </Site>
      <Site>
        <Site>StandVirtual</Site>
      </Site>
    </ExportSites>`

Comment: You were on the right track suggesting to add a `ROOT` element, but you still have a row's name defined in `PATH()`...